# Joining two tables on column that contains duplicates while maintaining original row count from 1st table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have two tables:

```
 TABLE 1                     TABLE 2

 ID  CODE  GROUP             ID  PICKNO   REQUESTDATE  CANCELDATE   INVOICENO
 ----------------            -------------------------------------------------
 1   123   A                 1   1        10-2-2013    10-4-2013    248
 2   144   A                 1   2        10-2-2013    10-4-2013    289
 3   154   A                 1   3        10-2-2013    10-4-2013    289
 1   211   B                 1   4        10-2-2013    10-4-2013    289
 3   149   C                 2   5        10-14-2013   10-15-2013   255
 1   200   A                 2   6        10-14-2013   10-15-2013   313
 1   133   A                 3   7        10-20-2013   10-21-2013   313
```

I want to add the `REQUESTDATE` and `CANCELDATE` columns to the table on the left. Every `ID` has only one<strike>, unique</strike>`REQUESTDATE` and only one<strike>, unique</strike> `CANCELDATE` (Everywhere `ID=1`, the `REQUESTDATE` is `10-2-2013` and the `CANCELDATE` is `10-4-2013`)

Simply left-joining on `ID` gives me a lot more rows than I started with because of the duplicate `ID` values. I would like only the original rows from TABLE 1 with the appropriate `CANCELDATE`s and `REQUESTDATE`s. Here is a snapshot of the desired result:

```
TABLE 1                     
ID  CODE  GROUP  REQUESTDATE  CANCELDATE
1   123   A      10-2-2013    10-4-2013
2   144   A      10-14-2013   10-15-2013
3   154   A      10-20-2013   10-21-2013
1   211   B      10-2-2013    10-4-2013
3   149   C      10-20-2013   10-21-2013
1   200   A      10-2-2013    10-4-2013
1   133   A      10-2-2013    10-4-2013
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Every ID has only one REQUESTDATE and one CANCELDATE, but different IDs can have the same CANCELDATE and/or REQUESTDATE as another ID.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your statement `Every ID has only one, unique REQUESTDATE and only one, unique CANCELDATE`, you can collapse all those to a single row:

```
select
id,
requestdate,
canceldate
from 
table2
group by 
id,
requestdate,
canceldate
```

That will get you a single row per ID.  You can join to that as a derived table:

```
select
...
from
table1
join ( select
    id,
    requestdate,
    canceldate
    from 
    table2
    group by 
    id,
    requestdate,
    canceldate1) t2
on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: So it's actually that every ID has only one REQUESTDATE and one CANCELDATE, but different IDs can have the same CANCELDATE and/or REQUESTDATE as another ID. Will this change the first query at all?

Comment: No, you'll get a row for every combination of id,requestdate, and canceldate.

Answer (score 1):

This can do your work. If you want to add new columns in left table and update them with what you desire :

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
  ADD requestdate DATETIME NULL, canceldate DATETIME NULL

UPDATE t1
SET    t1.requestdate = t2.requestdate,
       t1.canceldate = t2.canceldate
FROM   Table1 t1
       JOIN (SELECT id,
                    requestdate,
                    canceldate
             FROM   Table2
             GROUP  BY id,requestdate,canceldate) AS t2
         ON t1.id = t2.id
```

If you only want to select the results :

```
select t1.*, t2.requestdate, t2.canceldate
FROM   Table1 t1
       JOIN (SELECT id,
                    requestdate,
                    canceldate
             FROM   Table2
             GROUP  BY id,requestdate,canceldate) AS t2
         ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd suggest the OP add columns to Table1 and then perform an `UPDATE`. The question doesn't indicate that he wants to update Table1 to include request and cancel dates. If the OP were to go with this solution, then the OP would also need to build or modify a procedure in order to keep Table1 up to date when Table2 is already receiving the data. Just using `SELECT` with a `JOIN` when the data is needed should be more than sufficient.

Comment: Sorry, I interpreted it incorrectly. He said, 'I want to add the REQUESTDATE and CANCELDATE columns to the table on the left.', so I thought he wanted new columns in table. Also, if I replace update ... set ....   with    select ......   in this query it will give the results and will be same as what Andrew suggested. :)

Comment: Actually, you may be right. I re-read the question and his desired example appears to represent a new Table1 with the date columns. Perhaps add a summary to your answer that briefly describes the SQL you propose (I can't remove my vote without an edit).

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Dates AS
    SELECT Id
          ,MAX(REQUESTDATE) AS RequestDate
          ,MAX(CANCELDATE) AS CancelDate
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY Id
)
SELECT Table1.ID
      ,Table1.CODE
      ,Table1.GROUP
      ,Dates.REQUESTDATE
      ,Dates.CANCELDATE
FROM Table1
     LEFT JOIN Dates
         ON Dates.Id = Table1.Id
```

You can replace the grouping in the Dates CTE with distinct if you like.
(Which will make date errors, i.e. where an Id have different dates, visible)